# Insert ruby in html class=" " property

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, insert, inject

This is probably really stupid but I've spent the last 2 hours trying to figure out how to do this with no luck at all.

Basically I need my html page to do the following:

```
<div class="circleElement">
...
</div>
```

But I need to add more classes to that div class with ruby, the classes are coming in from a text field in my database.

I tried inserting ruby like:

```
<div class="circleElement"+ <%= u.tag %> >...</div>
```

And many different variations of this line with no luck at all :(

I should add that u.tag holds exactly this string> "activeTag classicTag".... so it should append with no problems but it's not doing it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<div class="circleElement <%= u.tag %>" >...</div>
```

should work.

Comment: OH MY GOD.... yes it did work.  Thank you very very much!!!  I was under the impression that <%= inside of double quotes would not get read as ruby!!  This will open up many doors, it's so simple :)

Comment: In ERB, everything inside `<% ... %>` gets evaluated regardless of context. The exception is nesting where `<%= " <%= ...%> " %>` is not valid.